# Changing app icon on iPhone error "The file doesn’t exist."

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, icons, appicon

I am trying to change the app icon through code, but it does not seem to work. Below is my info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>icon_60pt</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleAlternateIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>AppIcon-2</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>icon.dark_60pt</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Here is the code I am using to change the icon:

```
@objc func changeIcon() {
    //Check if the app supports alternating icons
    guard UIApplication.shared.supportsAlternateIcons else {
        return;
    }
    
    let name = "icon.dark_60pt"
    //Change the icon to a specific image with given name
    UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName(name) { (error) in
        //After app icon changed, print our error or success message
        if let error = error {
            print("App icon failed to due to \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            print("App icon changed successfully.")
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, here is the folder with the app icons: [App icon folder screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JgfX.png)

As you can see, I am using the same name everywhere "icon.dark_60pt", but I still get an error "The file doesn’t exist."

> App icon failed to due to Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file doesn’t exist." UserInfo={_LSLine=191, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000026e85d0 {Error Domain=LSApplicationWorkspaceErrorDomain Code=-105 "iconName not found in CFBundleAlternateIcons entry" UserInfo={_LSLine=179, NSLocalizedDescription=iconName not found in CFBundleAlternateIcons entry, _LSFunction=-[LSAltIconManager _setAlternateIconName:forIdentifier:withIconsDictionary:error:]}}, _LSFunction=-[LSAltIconManager _setAlternateIconName:forIdentifier:withIconsDictionary:error:]}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding them to your project bundle again but don't use a folder. Make sure to check the option "copy items if needed".

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks, just tried it - still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use the name of the icon, not the name of the file. Change the let name line with this:

```
let name = "AppIcon-2"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you are right. Its weird, because in multiple tutorials that I followed, everyone used the name of the file instead... I supposed Apple changed it..? Thanks anyway!